# Azure YAML Deployments are very slow

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am using azure YAML pipelines to deploy my .Net application. Generally, a deployment uses to complete in 30 min for one server.

But, for the past three days, it's taking almost 90 mins for deployment.
My org network is good and in the Azure status check pipelines are in advisory mode with below message **"expect start time delays up to 30 minutes for macOS hosted pipelines during peak hours"**

Is there any recent update from Microsoft related to YAML pipeline performance?

Comment: Hi, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You could check this page: [Azure DevOps Status](https://status.dev.azure.com/), if Azure DevOps has event issue, we could check latest news in the Status page.

And I found this event issue: [Advisory: expect start time delays up to 30 minutes for macOS hosted pipelines during peak hours](https://status.dev.azure.com/_event/233282345)

The latest news and workaround is: Customers will continue to see daily queueing during peak hours for macOS pools on Azure Pipelines due to a capacity shortage. We’re adding additional capacity over the next 3 months. Until the shortage is resolved, customers should expect queueing during peak hours.

As a workaround, customers can add self-hosted macOS agents to add new capacity for running their Pipelines: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-osx?view=azure-devops